# How do I make these four boxes to size according to the screen size?

Tags: css

[Website URL](http://digitalsnacks.co.uk)

I'd like those four boxes to fill the right side of the website. Can anyone help me a bit?

Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll post the code right away

Comment: `.brick-big { width: 580px; }` ----> `.brick-big { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use a percentage width.

```css
.brick-big {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `width: 98%;` to `.brick` or `width: calc(100% - 20px);` for a better result.

```
.brick {
   margin: 10px;
   width: calc(100% - 20px); /*add this for a better result*/
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue